# Unable to Start the libvirt-bin

Tags: openstack, libvirt

When I try to start libvirtd using libvirtd I get this error message:

```
  2014-05-06 14:12:36.148+0000: 13246: info : libvirt version: 1.2.2
  2014-05-06 14:12:36.148+0000: 13246: error : virPidFileAcquirePath:411 : Failed to acquire pid file '/var/run/libvirtd.pid': Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I am using openstack icehouse package in Ubuntu 12.04 server. What can fix this ?

Comment: Did you try as root?

Comment: Executing this libvirt command in root only

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this occurs because of one of two conditions: you either have another instance of libvirtd running, or the previous instance died unexpectedly, leaving its old /var/run/libvirtd.pid file around.

You can easily distinguish between the two:

```
  ps ax | grep libvirtd
```

will return a process in the first case, or just *grep* in the second one. You solve the problem by killing the running instance of *libvirtd* (if you have one), and then by removing by hand the file */var/run/libvirtd.pid* .

Comment: that made it worse for me : `2017-05-28 07:50:12.231+0000: 5786: error : qemuMonitorJSONCheckError:387 : internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'query-cpu-definitions': The command query-cpu-definitions has not been found
2017-05-28 07:50:12.231+0000: 5786: warning : virQEMUCapsLogProbeFailure:4441 : Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/bin/qemu-system-xtensaeb: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'query-cpu-definitions': The command query-cpu-definitions has not been found`

Comment: @tatsu What you report has nothing to do with what I posted.

Comment: oh ok i've made a question : https://superuser.com/questions/1213642/unable-to-start-libvirtd